# I HAVE SOME TEXT FILE WITH SAME CONTENT BUT DIFFERENT FILES NAME. BUT I GOT DIFFERENT HASH VALUE FOR ALL MY SAME CONTENT FILE

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import hashlib
import os

fileDir = 'F:\\hashcodepy'
files_list = []
for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(fileDir):
    for f in filenames:
        files_list.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath,f)))
filehashcode = []
buffer_size = 1024
hash_code = hashlib.md5()
for x in files_list:
    f1 = open(x,'rb').read(buffer_size)
    hash_code.update(f1)
    filehashcode.append(hash_code.hexdigest())
print(filehashcode)
```

THIS IS MY CODE. RUN WITHOUT ERROR. BUT I GOT ALL HASH CODE VALUES ARE DIFFERENT. I HAVE SAME FILES WITH DIFFERENT NAME. WHEN I RUN PROGRAMME WITH MANUALLY ENTERED FILES THEN I GOT SAME HASH VALUE. ALL FILES IN F:\ DRIVE WITH hashcodepy DIRECTORY. INSIDE THIS DIRECTORY I HAVE COPIED SAME FILE AGAIN AND AGAIN.
PLEASE SHOW ME SOME SUGGESTION.
THANK YOU.

Comment: Don't yell at us... What have we done??? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-using the same hash object for all files, without resetting it. Notice the following from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) for `hash.update()`:

> Repeated calls are equivalent to a single call with the concatenation of all the arguments: m.update(a); m.update(b) is equivalent to m.update(a+b).

Comment: I am new to python. so please can you explain in details. If possible can you change my code and show how to do that. Thank a lot.

Comment: Thank a lot TURE PALSSON. Now i got my results. Thanks